# Recreate MSDB for SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My SQL Server Express database's `msdb` file has become 'suspect'. All the other mdf files seem to be OK.

I now need to recreate the `msdb` file, but I do not have a backup for it (guilty as charged!). I have backups for my other DBs. This is what I found [from this blog](http://blog.sqltechie.com/2008/07/how-to-restore-msdb-database-if-your.html):

> If your msdb goes suspect then you have two choices, if you have
>   backup of database then restore it else you have to recreate it
>
> If you want to recreate it here are the steps to do it
>
> 1. Start the server with trace flag 3608. Detach the damaged `msdb`
> 2. Navigate to the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>      Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn` and start `sqlservr.exe -c -T3608`
> 3. Move or rename the damaged `msdb` files
> 4. Go to the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>      Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Install` and run the `instmsdb` file.
> 5. Restart SQL Server without the 3608 trace flag

Has someone done this before? I would like to get opinions or better suggestions before I break things more.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
My advice to anyone is to treat SQL Express like any production DB.  Have rigorous back-up policy and make sure you back-up your system databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either recreate as above or restore it.

The info above is [similar to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx), see "Creating a New msdb Database".

Note: if this came from Paul Randal's blog or the SQL Server Storage Engine then you can trust it

Comment: Thanks for response, but I follow the MSDN instructions, but it wont allow me to detach the database: 'Cannot detach an opened database when the server is in minimally configured mode'

Comment: @CyMark: verify you are following all steps correctly and to the letter

Comment: Thanks found my error: I used -c to start the server (Step 1 of Paul Randall's blog).  For SQL Server 2008 seems if you use this switch then you cannot detach the msdb.  I omitted it and bingo!  Thanks again for your time to reply.